# Arduino UNO, GRBL, OpenCncPilot, max velocity/speed, max acceleration, for laser cutting

Tags: arduino

I am testing GRBL for laser cutting..

In (defaults.h), i set default velocity to 40000mm/min, and default acceleration to 4000mm/sec2.
#ifdef DEFAULTS_GENERIC
// Grbl generic default settings. Should work across different machines.
#define DEFAULT_X_MAX_RATE 40000.0 // mm/min
#define DEFAULT_Y_MAX_RATE 40000.0 // mm/min
#define DEFAULT_Z_MAX_RATE 40000.0 // mm/min
#define DEFAULT_X_ACCELERATION  (4000.0*60*60) // 10*60*60 mm/min^2 = 10 mm/sec^2
#define DEFAULT_Y_ACCELERATION (4000.0*60*60) // 10*60*60 mm/min^2 = 10 mm/sec^2
#define DEFAULT_Z_ACCELERATION (4000.0*60*60) // 10*60*60 mm/min^2 = 10 mm/sec^2

In (config.h) i define machine configuration.
#define DEFAULTS_GENERIC

in G-Code i set feed rate to 20000mm/min (F20000).

But i get very slow move movements, anybody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

First I would check your hardware juper setup since usually it is possible to use the so called microsteps that in fact multiplies the number of steps needed for 1 stepper motor revolution by 2,4,8,16... Second you need to check the number of steps per revolution of your stepper motor (usually is 200, but are commonly used also 4,8,16..400 variants). Then see the diameter of your pulleys to calculate the linear movement done by the machine for one revolution of your stepper motor. You are ready now to do your math to adapt the variable settings to your hardware.
Moreover, once you have done your math, maybe, you will realize that your parameters are too high for your machine and the stepper motors simply are not able to keep up with the high rate of pulses that you are sending to them. This is why, maybe, your motors are turning slowly. At last, I would check your power supply to be sure that you are providing the correct voltage and current to your motor: this may be another reason why your motors are turning slowly.

Comment: Thanks :-), but the problem is not hardware, i have no hardware connected, but i can see on the graphics it is moving very slow, no matter what setting i type in to the (defaults.h).

Comment: You are welcome. Try to reduce your speed parameters. Asking 40000 mm/min equals to 666 mm/s. I do not know your machine but most likely there is no way for your stepepr motor to keep up with that pulse rate. On my laser cutting I use 10 mm/sec for cutting and 200 mm/sec for high speed engraving. The long answer is doing the proper math as I have explained in my answer. As a rule of thumb try to reduce your paramenters to default velocity to 6000 mm/min, and default acceleration to 400mm/sec2. Hope this helps